# Translation SQL query to ActiveRecord (Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have encountered difficulties in translating SQL query to ActiveRecord performance. I would be grateful for their assistance!

```
SELECT MAX(distances.max) from 
    (SELECT max(distance) 
        FROM 
            (SELECT * from tracks WHERE car_id=1) t , locations l 
        WHERE t.id=l.track_id 
        GROUP BY track_id) distances;
```

Comment: Do you have a Distance model?

Comment: Have you heard of [heredocs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents)?

Comment: No, I have only Track and Car model, distances is an alias for the subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def max_track_length
    sql= Location.select("MAX(distance) as distance")
            .joins("INNER JOIN tracks ON tracks.id=locations.track_id")
            .where("tracks.car_id = ?", self.id).group(:track_id).to_sql
    res=Car.from("(#{sql}) l").maximum("l.distance")
    res||=0;
end
```